# The exact code from python documentation doesn't work! (Importing modules)

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import, importerror

I have problem with importing modules which explained here https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

I created the exact files like [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages)

> ```
> sound/                          Top-level package
>       __init__.py               Initialize the sound package
>       formats/                  Subpackage for file format conversions
>               __init__.py
>               wavread.py
>               wavwrite.py
>               aiffread.py
>               aiffwrite.py
>               auread.py
>               auwrite.py
>               ...
>       effects/                  Subpackage for sound effects
>               __init__.py
>               echo.py
>               surround.py
>               reverse.py
>               ...
>       filters/                  Subpackage for filters
>               __init__.py
>               equalizer.py
>               vocoder.py
>               karaoke.py
>               ...
> ```

and I defined a variable inside each file like this : `in_<filename> = 'in <filename>'`

for example in `sound/effects/echo.py` I have `in_echo = 'in echo'`

now as you can see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references), in paragraph 1

> For example, if the module sound.filters.vocoder needs to use the echo
> module in the sound.effects package, it can use `from sound.effects import echo`.

so I modified `sound/filters/vocoder.py` like this:

```
from sound.effects import echo


print(echo.in_echo)

in_vocoder = 'in vocoder'
```

but when I run `vocoder.py` I get this error:

```
$ python3 -u "/home/something/sound/filters/vocoder.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/something/sound/filters/vocoder.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sound.effects import echo
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sound'
```

and also as you can see in same section, in paragraph 2

> From the surround module for example, you might use:
>
> ```
> from . import echo
> from .. import formats
> from ..filters import equalizer
> ```

so I modified `sound/effects/surround.py` like this:

```
from . import echo


print(echo.in_echo)

in_surround = 'in surround'
```

but when I run `surround.py` I get this error:

```
$ python3 -u "/home/something/sound/effects/surround.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/something/sound/effects/surround.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import echo
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

it's the same for these too

```
from .. import formats
from ..filters import equalizer
```

I am so confused and I would appreciate any explanation about why the exact code from python documentation doesn't work!!!


Thank you very much for your time

Comment: Do you have the sound library installed? Try doing a pip install.

Comment: You missed the point.  They're CREATING this package.

Comment: @HenryCWong the are local files my friend!!!

Comment: @TimRoberts what do you mean. what should I do to create the package? as far as I know when there we have some modules, we call them a package.

Comment: That's a package, called "sound".  It's intended to be used as a single unit.  You are trying to run one of the elements of that package by itself.  That's not the intended use case.

Comment: @TimRoberts how can we use them as a single unit? there is no other python file to run! can you give me an example please?

Answer (score 2):

The tutorial you're reading is talking about when another package imports this whole library using `import sound`.  In that case, the references work, because it has a starting point.  It doesn't work if you run a single script deep inside the package.  That's not how packages are supposed to work.

Now, you CAN make this work.  If you need "vocoder.py" to run on its own,  you just need to add the top-level directory to the path before importing.  As in:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append( os.path.abspath( os.path.basename(__file__) + "../.."))
```

Now you can import "effects.echo", for example.

Comment: Sir what's the point of `import sound`? to have access to it's variables and functions and etc (correct me if I'm wrong). So when I add `import sound` in a file that's in the same directory as the `sound` is, I must have access to everything inside `sound`. But still I can't have access to a variable if I use one those methods.  for example `sound.filters.vocoder.echo.in_echo`

Comment: Read the section in https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages that explains how a single module in the package can be imported.

Comment: `import sound` would be used by some OTHER application that wanted to use the facilities in this package.  That application has to make sure your top-level directory is on the path.  Inside the package, you have to use other methods to travel between the directories.  Remember, what you have up there is NOT an application.  It's a library for use by other applications.